# Did Butler ever explain how the Oankali sex system evolved?

Tags: liliths-brood

The Oankali system of sex (w/ Ooloi as a third sex, and from three to five members involved in mating, w/ two from another species) is interesting but I am having trouble thinking of how it would evolve. Did Butler ever explore how such a system would evolve?

Comment: Not related to the question, but you'd have to assume that it evolved on a planet with more than one major species.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No...

Octavia Butler doesn't seem to have explained how the Oankali system of reproduction would have evolved.

## But...

**Professor Joan Slonczewski** (a microbiologist at Kenyon College and also a published sci-fi novelist) made an attempt to address this particular question, in a conference paper titled **"Octavia Butler's *Xenogenesis* Trilogy: A Biologist's Response":**

> How could a species naturally evolve a lifestyle requiring the acquisition of genes from unrelated species? In the years since Dawn was published, research has revealed interesting parallels to the Oankali in the population dynamics of living organisms on Earth. Microbes and plants have been shown to possess surprising capacities for "genetic trade" with other species, even taking up naked DNA released by dead organisms and incorporating it into their own chromosomes. Our current view of bacteria is that, like the Oankali, these single-celled organisms evolve so as to keep only the limited set of genes they need for their current environment, but retain nearly endless capacity to acquire new genes, such as genes for antibiotic resistance, from DNA "out there." Similarly, plants in the natural environment have shown an unexpected capacity to acquire herbicide resistance genes from crop plants genetically engineered for resistance, a discouraging sign for the future of weed control.

You can read more of Slonczewski's paper [here](http://biology.kenyon.edu/slonc/books/butler1.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are some hints in chapter Metamorphosis/4 of *Imago*, where Jodahs describes the Oankali organelle:

> Ooloi said we *were* that organelle—that the original Oankali has evolved though the organelle's invasion, acquisition, duplication, and symbiosis.

This appears to be very similar to the [endosymbiotic theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiogenesis) of the development of mitochondria and chloroplasts from formerly free-living prokaryotes.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't made completely clear. Although Butler is a very systematic thinker, across a lot of axes, and, reading the Xenogenesis books -- as I'm doing right now! -- I am pretty sure she had some explanation worked out in her own mind.

A complex and complicating factor is that the Ooloi (the "third sex" among the Oankali) are capable of "constructing" children, and in fact Oankali mating, as we see it, seems to require that the Ooloi partner actively, consciously, intelligently, and in a skill- and tool-using type of way construct the... the zygote??... from the "genetic contributions" of both (or of all four) partners. How *that* system evolved -- and what it evolved from -- is indeed an intriguing question.

To the original question, though: what I gather is that the "two parents from another species" is only required during specific periods, that is, during the period of a gene trade with another species. During the long inter-trade periods when they are living on their ships, traveling through space and seeking a new trade-partner species, Oankali mating groups only involve three adult partners (male, female, and Ooloi), all members of the same (Oankali) species.

When the Oankali find a suitable new partner species (call it Species B), at that point, the three-way mating system becomes a five-way mating system[*], which is capable of happening because of the Oolois' skill in manipulating and reassembling biological and genetic material. The resulting generation of children is a generation of "constructs," blended together from both the Oankali and Species B. The gender/sex system of the construct generation follows the Oankali pattern: some children will develop as male, some as female, and some as Ooloi.

What happens then, going forward, is that the "constructs" now *are* the new Oankali, changed and transformed, as they always are, by their encounter with the new species. They will engage in three-way matings among themselves until, however many centuries and generations later, it's time for the next partner species and the next gene trade.

Among the questions that don't seem to be fully addressed is whether, in the run-up to a gene trade, a generation of Oankali always need to be specially biologically-constructed, and/or reared and socialized, in preparation for their future as five-way mating participants with the new species. In *Dawn*, there are implications that this is what happens with, e.g., the Ooloi child Nikanj, which has been intended since before its birth to bond and mate with humans.

But then again, we're also left with the impression that the Oankali "trade" with humanity is unusual in several ways -- among them, the very long time the Oankali have to spend reestablishing Earth as a habitable environment. Do they always have enough time to "breed" a special generation for interaction with the new partners? Maybe they do! But maybe not? It doesn't seem really clear.

[*] The apparent presumption of universally binary gender systems in all species (except the Oankali?), and of universally "normative" sexuality in all species (including both humans and Oankali), seems to me one of the oddities and perhaps weaknesses of Butler's approach to and/or worldbuilding in Xenogenesis. But I'm sure this topic has been amply discussed elsewhere, so I won't follow it further here.